# Error in running HAXM

Tags: android

[image]

I am not unable to run instance of HAXM.I have successfully installed HAXM and also enabled Intel virtualization technology vt-x in bios settings.Still it is not working and showing to me this error.Please help me to remove this error as early as possible.

Comment: deactivate hyper-v and reboot your pc recheck that you enabled vt-x

Comment: how i can deactivate hyper -v

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/643650